# Redirecting user to previous page

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

What is the best way to redirect the user to the previous page when a POST-request has been processed in laravel? That is, to the page where the POST-form that the user used to send the POST request?

I could of course add a hidden field with the URL to that page, but there has to be a more convenient way?

Comment: Is the post always coming from the same page?

Comment: No, the post can come from different pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have plenty of methods in Laravel to do that:

```
return Redirect::back();
```

Is one you can use to send the user back to a post form he/she right posted to.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Seems like an undocumented function.